# How to create a cell with a button using SWT?

Tags: java, swt

I'd like to create a table using SWT, the table will include a column with button(s), like following UI:
https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/features/swt/data_binding/images/data_binding_property_pane1.gif

The question is: How to add a button to a cell? Can anyone provide me a tutorial? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for different kinds of [editing support](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJFaceTableAdvanced/article.html#jfacetable_editor). More precisely [DialogCellEditor](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/DialogCellEditor.html)